# Android - Can't get fragment context in toast message

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to get fragment context inside toast message, 
I tried `getActivity()` and `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` 
and `HomeFragment.class` and `HomeFragment.this`, and just `this`.

I also tried making a global variable that gets the context and passed it in the toast, but it doesn't work Nothing has worked. This is my fragment class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import net.cairobus.app.activities.ActivityMain;
import net.cairobus.app.app.AppController;
import net.cairobus.app.materialtest.R;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private String urlCitiesObj = "url";
    private static String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private TextView txtResponse;
    private String jsonResponse;
    //private Context globalContext = null;
    private Context globalContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();



    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        makeJsonArrayRequest();
        txtResponse = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);


        return layout;
    }

    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    }





    private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urlCitiesObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("GetCitiesResult");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray .length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jSONObject = jsonArray .getJSONObject(i);
                        String cityID = jSONObject .getString("CityID");
                        String cityName = jSONObject .getString("CityName");

                        jsonResponse += "CityID: " + cityID  + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "CityName: " + cityName  + "\n\n";

                        txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                    }

                    if( isAdded()){
                        getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }






    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you mean the toast doesn't appear?

Comment: So this doesn't work?

`Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: show us your JsonObjectRequest class. I guess your callback doesn't called on UIThread, that's why you cannot see any Toasts;

Comment: @Tareq I need to know how you implement this class ```JsonObjectRequest```.

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam it's from the volley library

Comment: Post your exceptions.

Comment: Hm I'm not familiar with Volley to tell any further. But for now [Kamran's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31871329/1553254) is a good workaround.

Comment: Take a look at this [volley sample](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/volley/simple.html) . It seems that onResponse is called on the UI Thread

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam I tried his work around but it didn't work, as for the exception, this is what I get _http://i.imgur.com/sqiMa82.jpg_

Comment: I searched a bit an casting null seem to solve the problem for some people. could you test that `JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urlCitiesObj, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()` an alternative is in my edited answer, please also check that.

Comment: well now the error is gone but it gives me a null pointer exception at these lines http://imgur.com/VVrwCTc,AO3GD9N,A77ypsC#0

Comment: Please accept an answer and open a new question for this. Keep your questions short and try dont start discussions. Thanks a lot. This might also the reason for the downvotes. I'll try to help you with the next question.

Comment: Accept an answer or post your own solution if your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.
 */
final public Activity getActivity() {
    return mActivity;
}
```

You must use getActivity() after onAttach(Activity activity) lifecycle method callbacked

Comment: it doesn't work, even after I move my onAttach above the method

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference to the `Activty` in `onAttatch()` and use that:

```
private Activity mActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
}
```

`getActivity()` will return `null` if the Fragment is not associated with an `Activity` (yet).

For the same reason the following lines do not work.

```
private Context globalContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

Because at this point the `Fragment` is not associated to an `Activity` .

**Addition:**

If you take a look at the source code of the fragment:

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    mCalled = true;
}

final public FragmentActivity getActivity() {
    return mActivity;
}
```

Note that `mActivity` is **not** assigned `onAttach()`

---

**Alternative solutions:**

checking:

```
if( getActivity() == null){
    // not assigent to an Activity
}
```

this also works pretty well:

[isAdded()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded())

> Return true if the fragment is currently added to its activity.

```
if( isAdded()){
    getActivity() // will not return null
}
```

**Addition to the cannot resolve constructor problem:**

Try to change:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            urlCitiesObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

to

```
JSONObject obj = null;
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            urlCitiesObj, obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

or

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        urlCitiesObj, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

Comment: A proper way to see if your fragment is attached or not, without using redundant object is to call ```isAdded()``` which check your activity object as well. I guess not many guys out there know about that method, but it's really helpful

Comment: @Nguyễn Hoài Nam you are right. There are multiple solutions. Also checking getActivity() == null might do the job.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Here is the code of isAdded(): ```return mActivity != null && mAdded;```. So there is one more thing we need to check, if we want to check. Since Google check it for us, why not just use a well created method ;)

Comment: where exactly can I add this "isAdded()" method? How does the code look like?

Comment: @TareqEl-Masri please take a look at my comment on your question. If you are about to use isAdded(), just use it right before your Toast calling. But I suspect there're other reasons, depending on your Async Callback, so please give us more codes

Comment: @Tareq El-Masri check the last part of my answer ive edited it. also take care of  Nguyễn Hoài Nam 's comments.

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam I edited the question and added the full code to my fragment, it still doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do anything on the UI, you have to take care that you're doing it from the `UI thread`.

Change:

```
Toast.makeText("This is where I need context", "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to:

```
getActivity().runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText("This is where I need context", "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

and the same modification for `txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);`